Simplifying $(\cos2x + \cos3x) (\cos4x + \cos6x) (\cos x + \cos5x)$, where $13x = 2\pi$

If: $13x = 2\pi$, simplify:
$$M = (\cos2x + \cos3x) (\cos4x + \cos6x) (\cos x + \cos5x)$$
A) $\;-1/8\quad$
B) $\;1/16\quad$
C) $\;1/8\quad$
D) $\;- 1/16\quad$
E) $\;-1/2$


Where is your Approach  ? Please include your Approach otherwise the question will be downvoated.

On a TI-84 calculator, you can simply put $2\pi/13 \rightarrow X$, hit enter, and then type in the formula.

This question is similar to: Find the value of : $\cos x \cos 2x...\cos 999x$ given that $x=\frac {2\pi}{1999}$. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@IITRoorkee That was quite an edit :) I don't know why it has been approved.

What you've done uptil now is correct,
Further my approach is to write these as
$2^{3}\cos(\frac{2\pi}{13})×\cos(\frac{4\pi}{13})×(-\cos(\frac{8\pi}{13}))   
 ×(-\cos(\frac{3π}{13}))×\cos(\frac{6π}{13})×(-\cos(\frac{12π}{13}))$.
Now, multiply and divide by
$2^{3}\sin(\frac{2π}{13})\sin(\frac{3π}{13})$
And obtain
$\frac{(-\sin(\frac{24π}{13})×\sin(\frac{16π}{13}))}{\sin(\frac{2π}{13})\sin(3π/13)}$
We obtain $\frac{-1}{8}$.
I hope this helps.

Alternatively, writing $\dfrac\pi{13}=x$ and using $\cos(2m\pi\pm y)=\cos y$ and $\sin2A=2\sin A\cos A,$
$$2^3\cos2x\cos4x(-\cos8x)(-\cos3x)\cos6x(-\cos12x)$$
$$=8\cos2x\cos4x(-\cos8x)(\cos(13x+3x))\cos(26x+6x)(-\cos(52x+12x))\text{ as }13x=\pi$$
$$=\cdots$$
$$=\dfrac{8\sin128x}{2^6\sin2x}$$
Now $\sin128x=\sin(130x-2x)=\sin(10\pi-2x)=-\sin2x$

Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., basic help on mathjax notation, mathjax tutorial and quick reference, main meta site math tutorial and equation editing how-to.
